# How to connect Laravel 8 to oracle 11g database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, web, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect **Laravel 8** to the **Oracle 11g** database, I tried all possible solutions but it didn't work.
Here are my system properties:

1. Windows 8.1 64 bits.
2. Laravel 8.
3. Oracle 11g.
4. Xampp 64 bits.
5. PHP 7.4.10

**This is the error message:** C:\xampp\htdocs>composer require yajra/laravel-oci8
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_11g' (tried:
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp
php\ext\php_php_oci8_11g.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unkn
own on line 0
.
.
.
The following image clarifies the problem:
[image]

Comment: You are missing that extension, may be you just need to edit your php.ini and reload php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment `extension=oci8_12c` in your php.ini file and make sure `php_oci8_12c.dll` file in there in your `ext` folder.

Comment: I'm using oracle 11g (php_oci8_11g.dll), and and I uncomment the extension=php_oci8_11g.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `extension=oci8_12c` by removing `;` before it in you php.ini and then relaod php-fpm using `service php-fpm restart` or `service php7-fpm restart` replace 7 with your php version.

It seems it is moved to [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8), download dll file and place that in `xampp\php\ext\` directory. if exists replace it, restart your xampp and it should be okay now.

Comment: I'm using oracle 11g (php_oci8_11g.dll), and and I uncomment the extension=php_oci8_11g.

Comment: @Jon what I understand is, your extension should be there, you do not need to install, it still, can you use `php -m` and check if you can see the extension, if not, we need to install it.

Comment: extension does not exist when I used php -m.

Comment: @Jon check updated answer, download the dll and place it in correct path, restart your xampp.

Comment: @Jon any progress and update, what is the current status if you will let me know, then only I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem with:

```
composer remove yajra/laravel-oci8

composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^10.0
```

If the error dont dissappear just try different versions and remember to configure your database in /config/database.php

docs: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-oci8/9.0